# Qual é a melhor forma de fazer um if-else?

Tags: c, if, lógica

Os dois exemplos abaixo são equivalentes, mas qual representa a melhor forma de fazer um `if-else`? Meu objetivo é exibir `"num é igual a 0"` se `num` for igual a 0, e `"num é diferente de 0"` caso `num` possua qualquer outro valor numérico.

Código 1

```c
if (num == 0)
  puts("num eh igual a 0");
else
  puts("num eh diferente de 0");
```

Código 2

```c
if (num != 0)
  puts("num eh diferente de 0");
else
  puts("num eh igual a 0");
```

Sempre que vou escrever um `if-else` eu travo e tenho essa dúvida, se deveria tratar primeiro a condição específica no `If` e deixar as restantes para o `Else` como no Código 1, ou o contrário disso, tratando primeiro a maioria dos casos no `If` e deixando o caso específico no `Else` como no Código 2.

Outra pergunta: suponhamos que eu tenha um `if-else` em que o blocos `if` e `else` possuam uma quantidade diferente de linhas de código, nesse caso a ordem importa? Digo, se faz diferença na elegância e legibilidade do código a opção que possuir maior número de linhas de código ser escrita primeiro (dentro do if) ou por último (dentro do else)?

Comment: Geralmente é preferível o Código 1, mas tudo depende... a ideia é deixar o código o mais rapidamente compreensível possível e, na maioria das vezes, uma negação pode confundir um pouco mais, porém num trecho de validação de dados pode ser que faça mais sentido o Código 2. Enfim, depende... Sobre a segunda pergunta, particularmente, nunca vi alguém com essa neura e acho que não faz tanta diferença, tendo em vista que se um if/else ficar muito grande você pode separá-lo em métodos menores. Como dica, dê uma olhada no livro "Clean Code".

Comment: Talvez, dependendo do caso, possa ter alguma diferença de desempenho por causa do [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809), mas aí vc só vai saber depois que testar. Mas a princípio, "tanto faz", depende muito de cada caso.

Answer (score 1):

Bem no caso que descreveste mais vale fazer

```
If(num){
   puts("num eh diferente de 0");
}else{
   puts("num eh igual a 0");
}
```

O código e lido de cima **para baixo por isso convém meteres a instrução mais leve e que descarte o máximo de opções no primeiro if**, **mas tenta usar o switch o máximo possível** já que este tem propriedades ligeiramente mais complexas do que ler de cima para baixo.
Quanto ao compilador a velocidade com que ele faz == ou != e igual ja que primeiro existem varias instruções em x64 ou amd64 que fazem ambas as comparações mas segundo porque se ouvesse uma differença significativa entre os dois o proprio compilador C(a nao ser que estejas a usar algo obscuro) faz a optimização dessas pequenas instruções por ti
Por isso tem muito a ver com a legibilidade do código pessoalmente prefiro fazer:

```
if(algoeum){
  printf("a variavel não é 0");
}
```

Já que grande parte das pessoas lê a condição mais depressa do que doutras maneiras, mas isto depende de quem vai ler o teu codigo